# href for "Jabber / Google Chat" account

Tags: html

I am looking for a way to code a link to open an instant messaging program. I have found the ways to open aim and yahoo chat, but not Jabber. Any ideas?

```
AIM: <a href='aim:goim?screenname=foo'>foo</a>
Yahoo Chat: <a href='ymsgr:chat?foo'>foo</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to RFC, Jabber link should be xmpp:my@jid.tld

Answer (score 7):

Use `xmpp:alice@example.com?message` - obviously you have to replace the address.

See http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0032.html for details.